# Trouble installing hdbscan package for python : "no module named 'hdbscan'" error

Tags: python, linux, pip, hdbscan

I want to run an algorithm written in Python on my Ubuntu virtual machine. It needs to import the hdbscan module. I thus want to install it on my virtual machine.

Following the [documentation](https://pypi.org/project/hdbscan/)from Pypi.org about this library, I simply ran :

```
pip install hdbscan
```

After a few minutes, it returned :

```
Succesfully built hdbscan
Installing collected packages: hdbscan
Succesfully installed hdbscan-0.8.27
```

However, if I run my algorithm, it still says that there's "`No module named 'hdbscan'`".

I tried `pip uninstall hdbscan` but it then returns :

```
WARNING : Skipping hdbscan as it is not installed.
```

I have tried several commands to fix this issue, like for example
`sudo apt --reinstall install hdbscan`
or
`pip install --upgrade git+https://github.com/scikit-learn-contrib/hdbscan.git#egg=hdbscan`

All I get as a result is "successfully installed" or "requirement already satisfied" but my algorithm still can't use it, "is not installed" or "unable to locate package hdbscan" alternatively as I try one command or another.

I don't know what is the cause of the problem nor how to fix it. Can anyone help me please ?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem using Windows. I fixed it installing the various dependencies before and then hdbscan **out of any environment**.
I strictly recommend to run the terminal as administrator, otherwise some dependencies cannot be solved.

```
conda install cython
conda install numpy scipy
conda install scikit-learn
pip install hdbscan
```

Answer (score 0):

try this in your terminal

conda install -c conda-forge hdbscan